# file does not start with PNG signature

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, google-play-console

, I try to upload my flutter app on google play , when I write this command `flutter build appbundle` I got the error that told me

I try to write this command in my project to build grudle.aa file :
`flutter build appbandel` but I got those errors:

```
Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > Android resource compilation failed
        ERROR: AAPT: com.weenbalaqee.weenbalaqee.app-main-19:/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
        C:\myfolder\Myproject\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > Android resource compilation failed
        ERROR: AAPT: com.weenbalaqee.weenbalaqee.app-main-19:/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
       C:\myfolder\Myproject\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.




   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > Android resource compilation failed
        ERROR: AAPT: com.weenbalaqee.weenbalaqee.app-main-19:/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
       C:\myfolder\Myproject\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.



   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > Android resource compilation failed
        ERROR: AAPT: com.weenbalaqee.weenbalaqee.app-main-19:/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
      C:\myfolder\Myproject\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > Android resource compilation failed
        ERROR: AAPT: com.weenbalaqee.weenbalaqee.app-main-19:/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
       C:\myfolder\Myproject\main projects\WeenBlaqe\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at `/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png`? Is it a PNG file?

Comment: The file is png but when click it i show JPEG

Comment: Then its a jpeg file with a `.png` file extension. Convert it to a _real_ PNG file.

Comment: I don't know how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your file name is ic_launcher.png but it is manually renamed or by any kind it is not authentic png file.

Check [this](https://cloudconvert.com/jpeg-to-png) website, you can use this to convert all of your ic_launcher files to png.